# MySQL Joins not working as required

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I have two tables.

Table A:

```
root_id, root_text
```

Table B:

```
word_id , word_text,root_text
```

Now Some of the records of `Table B` has root_texts which might not exist in `Table A`.

So for that I am trying to use left join.

```
select *
from   A a , B b
where  a.root_text=+b.root_text
```

I only get the records which has matching **`root_text`**.

If I use the new way

```
Select
  *
from
  A left join B on a.root_text= b.root_text
```

I get so many extra records. I am Using MySQL 5.6.1.7

**UPDATE :**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b32a/2

Query I am running

```
select * from   word_detail w left  join roots r
on r.root_text =w.root
and w.surah_no=1
and w.verse_no=1
and w.word_no=1
```

What I am doing wrong ?

As in  result you see so many records which are not needed. The filter verse_no , word_no not working.

**Update**

The issue was after the left join we have to use where

```
select * from   word_detail w left  join roots r
    on r.root_text =w.root
    where w.surah_no=1
    and w.verse_no=1
    and w.word_no=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all records from TableB that are not present in table A you should use this:

```
Select *
from
  B left join A
  on a.root_text= b.root_text
where
  a.root_text is null
```

or if you want the opposite - all records from tableA that are not present on tableB:

```
Select *
from
  A left join B
  on a.root_text= b.root_text
where
  b.root_text is null
```

btw, this is not a left join on MySQL:

```
select * from A a , B b where a.root_text=+b.root_text
```

but will result as a simple INNER JOIN

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have created schemar in MySQL fiddle. – Makky just now   edit

Comment: @Makky a left join will return all rows from the table on the left, and only the rows from the table on the right where the join does succeed. You have to add a where tableright.column is null if you want only the rows from the left that have no corresponding record on the right

Comment: @Makky you can just add where r.root_text is null (root text is a column on the right side of the join and it's on the ON clause so it will be null only when there's no correspondence)

Comment: The issue was that I was using AND after the join ... It works if I use WHERE ... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` operator is not standard SQL, but specific to the Oracle RDBMS, so it will not work as expected on MySQL.

The `LEFT JOIN` syntax is correct, the "many extra records" stem from the data in your tables. You might want to use some sort of `WHERE` as a filter or an aggregate to group the result set to make it more managable.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have created schemar in MySQL fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is an inner join which explains why you are not getting as many results as when you are left joining. Left joining can also be thought of as a left outer join.